# Is there a way to save python objects to disk, that do not have a 'write' attribute

Tags: python, pickle

I saw that pickle is the standard way of saving python objects to disk. However, when I try this

```
pickle.dump( embeddings , 'embeddings.pickle', pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I get

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-ae20bbf8c8a9> in <module>()
----> 1 pickle.dump( embeddings , 'embeddings.pickle', pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)

TypeError: file must have a 'write' attribute
```

Is there way for python objects without  a 'write' attribute

Comment: What is `embeddings`? You could just use some adapter to convert it into a compliant form, or just manually read/write to/from disk

Comment: Does `dump` need a file handle rather than the file name as second argument? (Haven't used it myself, just looking at the docstring.)

Comment: From the help: _The *file* argument must have a write() method that accepts a single bytes argument._ Its a file like object. `open(''embeddings.pickle', 'wb')` should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument to `pickle.dump()` must be an open file, not a filename.

```
with open('embeddings.pickle', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump( embeddings , f, pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```